# Cannot create 2 foreign key

Tags: mysql

I tried to create 2 foreign keys in customerdetails table but it keeps me showing an error when I execute this query. Is there any problem with my query?

```
CREATE TABLE `vg_shippingdb`.`customerdetails` (
`CustomerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`Name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , 
`Age` INT NOT NULL , 
`Sex` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
`Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,  
PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`),
FOREIGN KEY (ReservedID) REFERENCES reservationdetails(ReservedID),
FOREIGN KEY (TicketID) REFERENCES ticket(TicketID)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `vg_shippingdb`.`reservationdetails` (
`ReservedID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`ReservedDate` DATE NOT NULL , 
`DepartureTime` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , 
`Destination` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL , 
`Accommodation` TEXT NULL , 
`NameOfVessel` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (`ReservedID`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `vg_shippingdb`.`ticket` ( 
`TicketID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`TicketNo` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , 
`Status` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (`TicketID`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

[image]

Comment: You are creating the `customerdetails` table before the `reservationdetails` table exists.

Comment: Try to execute the `use vg_shippingdb` before your ddl.And create the first table at last.

Comment: I tried to arrange but only one reserved foreign key has executed and showing error ticket table is not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns does not exist in a table really. Specifying the foreign key does not create a column, you must do it explicitly before the FK definition.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `vg_shippingdb`.`customerdetails` (
`CustomerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`Name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , 
`Age` INT NOT NULL , 
`Sex` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
`Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,  
PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`),
-- Create columns
ReservedID INT,
TicketID INT,
-- Then use them in FK expressions
FOREIGN KEY (ReservedID) REFERENCES reservationdetails(ReservedID),
FOREIGN KEY (TicketID) REFERENCES ticket(TicketID)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

PS. The table which FK is refferred on must be created firstly - FK cannot refer the table which will be created later.

Answer (score 1):

before creating foreign keys, create all tables

Answer (score 0):

First create **reservationdetails** and **ticket** then create **customerdetails**.

Note: First create source/referred table then create table with **FOREIGN KEY**